# io.ktor.client.features.ClientRequestException: Client request invalid

Tags: kotlin

When calling the getUser function, I make an HTTP request that retrieves information about a user.
If the user does not exist I get the error:

**io.ktor.client.features.ClientRequestException: Client request(https://api.intra.chocolat.fr/v2/users/fff) invalid: 404 Not Found. Text: "{}"**

I am unable to catch the error, and to continue the execution of the program.

```
package com.ksainthi.swifty.api

import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.Keep
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.call.*
import io.ktor.client.features.*
import io.ktor.client.features.json.*
import io.ktor.client.features.json.serializer.*
import io.ktor.client.features.observer.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import kotlinx.serialization.*

class Api42Service {
    @Keep
    @Serializable
    data class Token(
        @SerialName("access_token") val accessToken: String,
        @SerialName("token_type") val tokenType: String,
        @SerialName("expires_in") val expiresIn: Int,
        @SerialName("scope") val scope: String,
        @SerialName("created_at") val createdAt: Int
    )

    @Keep
    @Serializable
    data class User(
        @SerialName("id") val id: Int,
        @SerialName("email") val email: String,
        @SerialName("login") val login: String? = null,
        @SerialName("first_name") val firstName: String? = null,
        @SerialName("last_name") val lastName: String? = null,

        )

    private var accessToken: String? = null
    private var client: HttpClient = HttpClient() {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer(kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            })
        }




    }
    private val API_URL: String = "https://api.intra.chocolat.fr"
    private val API_SECRET: String =
        "<secret>"
    private val API_UID: String =
        "<api_uid>"


    suspend fun requestAPI(
        requestMethod: HttpMethod,
        path: String,
        params: MutableMap<String, String>?
    ): HttpResponse {

        val urlString = API_URL
            .plus(path)
        return client.request(urlString) {

            method = requestMethod

            params?.forEach { (key, value) ->
                parameter(key, value)
            }

            headers {
                accessToken?.let {
                    println(it)
                    append(HttpHeaders.Authorization, "Bearer $it")
                }
            }
        }
    }


    suspend fun getToken(): Token {
        val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()

        params["grant_type"] = "client_credentials";
        params["client_secret"] = API_SECRET;
        params["client_id"] = API_UID;


        val response = requestAPI(HttpMethod.Post, "/oauth/token", params);
        val token: Token = response.receive()

        accessToken = token.accessToken
        return token
    }

    suspend fun getUser(login: String): User? {

        try {
            val response = requestAPI(HttpMethod.Get, "/v2/users/$login", null);
            val user: User = response.receive()

            return user
        } catch (cause:  io.ktor.client.features.ClientRequestException) {
            Log.d("wtf", "Catch your error here")
        }
        return null
    }

}
```